# export data from parse.com to xls format

Tags: excel, parsing, xml-parsing, xls, parse-platform

i did this to get the result from parse.com

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

i can also send it to a .xls format with "cat" command

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore > gamescore.xls
```

but its a mess, it doesn't sort and class each value into a table and it is what i am looking for, please someone help me!

Thanks..

Comment: if you simply do a cat to .xls, won't all the data go into 1 cell in the form of json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort by score (descending), add -G --data-urlencode 'order=-score'
If you are really want to export your entire collection (i.e. you want to leave Parse) you should also check out Parse's one-click export at http://blog.parse.com/2012/03/09/one-click-export/